# access token from vuex store in vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

this is my getters which get the token from local storage

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getToken"])
  }
```

how can i access it in my axios.post request

```
    const pay = () => {
    

      elms.value.instance
        .createToken(cardElement, { price: price.value })
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          const token = result.token;

          const paymentData = {
            token: token.id,
            price: 100
          };

          axios
            .post("http://localhost:5000/api/pay", paymentData)
            .then(response => {
             
            })
        })
    };
```

Comment: using `computed: { }` is Options API syntax.  You shouldn't mix the two APIs.  Refer to the [vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html) on how to use vuex with Composition API.